# How to make table reload after users saves a new row to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the component initially loads, it does a get request to the database to build the table with the initial data. This works fine. The table is then comprised of child components. The components with data then have an update and delete button. It then loads one final child component with no data, just blank inputs and a save button. When the user clicks Save or Delete, I would like the table to re render to reflect these changes. This is where I am stuck.

I have tried calling the axios.get method after these buttons are clicked, changing the state, forceRender(), none of these reload the parent component.

Parent Comp

```
class ParentComp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
      this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
      this.state = {
        data: [],
        loading: false,
        newInput: false,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      this.GetData();
    }

    handler(){
      this.setState({newInput: true});
      console.log("Called");
    } 


    GetData(){
      axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
      const header = {
        headers:{
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('JWTAccess')
        }
      }
      axios.get("tableData/", header)
          .then(response => {
            this.setState({data: response.data,
              loading: true
            });
            console.log(this.state.expenses);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
      })
    }

    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
              </tr>
                {this.state.data.map(
                expenses => {
                return(                
                 <ChildComp key={Math.random()} name={data.title} dataId={data.id} value={data.value} empty={false} action={this.handler}/>                 
                );
                }
                )}
                < ChildComp key={Math.random()} name={''} dataId={''} value={''} empty={true} action={this.handler}/>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
  }
export default ParentComp;
```

Child Component with one of the axios calls (to not spam the thread):

```
class childComp extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handlePut = this.handlePut.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);       
        this.handleButtons = this.handleButtons.bind(this);
        this.action = this.handleButtons.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            dataId: this.props.dataId,
            name: this.props.name,
            value: this.props.value,
            empty: this.props.empty
        }
    }

    PostData(){
        axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
        const header = {
          headers:{
            'Authorization': "Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem('JWTAccess')
          }
        }
        const payload = {
          title: this.state.name,
          cost: this.state.value
        }
        axios.post("tableData/", payload, header)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
              })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
        })
      }

      handleDelete(){
          this.DeleteData();
          this.props.action();
      }

      handlePut(){
          this.PutData();
      }
      handleSubmit(){
        this.PostData();
        this.props.action();
      }

      handleButtons(){
          if(this.state.empty){
              return(
                  <td><button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Save</button></td>
              )
          }
          else{
              return(
                <td><button onClick = {this.handlePut}>Update</button><button onClick = {this.handleDelete}>Delete</button></td>
              )
          }
      }

    render(){
        return(
            <tr>
                <td><input
                  type="text"
                  name="name"
                  placeholder="name"
                  value={this.state.name}
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ name: e.target.value })}
                /></td>
                <td>$<input
                  type="text"
                  name="value"
                  placeholder="value"
                  value={this.state.value}
                  onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })}
                /></td>
                {this.handleButtons()}
            </tr>
        );
    }
};
export default ChildComp;
```

My end goal is for the parent comp to re render the table or entire component after the save (handleSubmit()) or delete (handleDelete()) buttons are clicked. Sorry if I posted a lot of code, I am still very new to JavaScript and React so I am still figuring out what the relevant information is. 
Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the parent method from your child to rerender the entire parent.

In parent

> ```
>  <ChildComp key={Math.random()} name={data.title} dataId={data.id}
>  value={data.value} empty={false} action={this.handler} getData =
>  {this.GetData}/>
> ```

In child

> ```
>  axios.post("tableData/", payload, header)
>             .then(response => {
>                 console.log(response);
>                 this.props.getData ()
>               })
>             .catch(error => {
>               console.log(error);
>         })
> ```

call get data once you get the result of the API in submit/delete.

Also avoid using  `key={Math.random()}` instead use database ids as key.

Comment: This is having an interesting result. It seems it is causing the re render, but it is causing it took quickly. If I do two actions, the second action will allow the previous action to render. Is this because it is rendering before the get/post/delete axios calls are completing?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest solution is calling setState().
 You can just add this.setState() call in  handleSubmit and handleDelete methods. like a

```
handleSubmit(){
    this.PostData();
    this.props.action();
    this.setState({something:something})
  }
```

every time you call setState your component do  re-render )

Comment: Just for learning purposes, handleSubmit is in the child component, so wouldn't changing the state would force the child component to re render but not the parent? I will try it now!

Comment: I just tried it and my assumption was correct, this only causes the childComp to re render, not the whole table. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand what you want it is easy tooo .add one extra prop in your child component.

```
class ParentComp extends Component{
 state={
   something:null
 }
reloadTable=()=>{
   this.setState(something:something);
} 
render(){ 
   return(
      <ChildComp actionForReloadTable={this.reloadTable}....></ChildComp>
     ) 
}
```

and in your ChildComponent's handleSubmit method add call this function **actionForReloadTable** in this way:

```
handleSubmit(){
  this.PostData();
  this.props.action();
  this.props.actionForReloadTable();
}
```